# Sprite onAreaTouch no response ontouch, Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I am trying to implement on my Sprite using onAreaTouch but no response while touching my sprite.

```
    androidTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 354,
            404, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    androidRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            androidTexture, this, "image.png", 0, 0);
    Sprite android = new Sprite(30, 500, androidRegion,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            System.out.println("touched");

            return true;
        }
    };
scene.registerTouchArea(android);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    androidTexture.load();
    scene.attachChild(android);
```

this code is in oncreatescene

i am really a newbie to andengine.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and added `pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);` in onCreateScene(). After running it, it can print "touched" in LogCat(not console) when I touched the image.

So, did you forget to add `pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);`?
You also need to add `pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();` in onCreateResources()

Answer (score 0):

Do not load resource in onCreateScene() . Instead, load all the resources in onCreateResources() . After that, attach your sprite in onCreateScene(). I think rest of your will works perfectly.

---

Happy Coding

Comment: thanks for your replay, but that didn't help me,, is there any other reason not firing ontouch, i also checked is there any other ontouch overeride.